# BITMAPINFOHEADER для полутонового изображения

Tags: графика, bitmap, bmp

Задача состоит в том, что

> Основным типом изображения при обработке, как правило, выступают полутоновые изображения. Процесс трансформации изображения из одного типа в другой может быть осуществлен по следующей схеме: полноцветные →
>   полутоновые → бинарные.
>
> Получить полутоновое изображение из полноцветного можно с помощью
>   формулы  = 0.3 + 0.59 + 0.11, где , ,  — значения
>   красного, зеленого и синего цветов соответственно,  — значение
>   интенсивности оттенков какого-либо цвета, например, серого. Значение 0
>   соответствует черному цвету (отсутствие интенсивности), значение
>   255—белому (максимальная интенсивность).

Так вот, мой вопрос заключается в том, как должен выглядеть `BITMAPINFOHEADER` полутонового изображения, в которое следует преобразить 24-/32-битное. Т. е. меня интересует поле `biBitCount` и структура самого изображения. Как это всё должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

biBitCount = 8. Сам заголовок должен находиться в смежном с палитрой участке памяти. Т.е. блок памяти должен быть размера sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+sizeof(RGBQUAD)*colors_count; В палитру записываешь нужные цвета. В твоём случае это одинаковые значения для всех полей структур RGBQUAD. Значение каждого пикселя будет индексом в палитре. Чтобы не запутаться, используй значения интенсивности идентичные индексу.
Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define COLOR_TABLE_COUNT   256
#define PIXELS_WIDTH    256
#define PIXELS_HEIGHT   600
#define FILE_NAME_BMP   "picture.bmp"

int main()
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER file_header;
    memset(&file_header, 0, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    file_header.bfType = 0x4d42;

    size_t info_header_size = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+sizeof(RGBQUAD)* COLOR_TABLE_COUNT;
    BITMAPINFO* info_header_ptr = (BITMAPINFO*)malloc(info_header_size);
    memset(info_header_ptr, 0, info_header_size);
    info_header_ptr->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info_header_ptr->bmiHeader.biWidth = PIXELS_WIDTH;
    info_header_ptr->bmiHeader.biHeight = -PIXELS_HEIGHT; // прямая развёртка
    info_header_ptr->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    info_header_ptr->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
    //info_header.biClrUsed = 0; // max colors, 2^biBitCount
    //info_header.biClrImportant = 0; // all colors from palette
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < COLOR_TABLE_COUNT; i++) // RGBQUAD, если используем BITMAPINFOHEADER. Для BITMAPCOREHEADER будет RGBTRIPLE
    {
        info_header_ptr->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = i;
        info_header_ptr->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = i;
        info_header_ptr->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = i;
    }
    file_header.bfOffBits = sizeof(file_header)+info_header_size;

    // заполняем градиентную линию (в 3 раза шире)
    BYTE pixel_row[PIXELS_WIDTH * 3];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < PIXELS_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        BYTE val = 255 - i * COLOR_TABLE_COUNT / PIXELS_WIDTH;
        pixel_row[i] = val;
        pixel_row[PIXELS_WIDTH * 2 - 1 - i] = val;
        pixel_row[PIXELS_WIDTH * 2 + i] = val;
    }
    // setting up gradient line into pixel array
    size_t scan_line_size = (PIXELS_WIDTH + 3) / 4 * 4; // выравнивание по DWORD
    size_t pixels_size = scan_line_size * PIXELS_HEIGHT; // полный размер
    BYTE* pixels = (BYTE*)malloc(pixels_size);
    memset(pixels, 0, pixels_size);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < PIXELS_HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&pixels[scan_line_size * i], &pixel_row[i % (PIXELS_WIDTH * 2)], PIXELS_WIDTH); // копируем со смещением
    }

    file_header.bfSize = file_header.bfOffBits + pixels_size;

    HANDLE bmp_file = CreateFile(FILE_NAME_BMP, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten;
    WriteFile(bmp_file, &file_header, sizeof(file_header), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(bmp_file, info_header_ptr, info_header_size, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(bmp_file, pixels, pixels_size, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    CloseHandle(bmp_file);
    free(pixels);
    free(info_header_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```